# Create wait view in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to put a *wait view* while executing a shell command set.

**For example:**

```
myfunction () {
# some commands
# npm install
# kill some
#...
}
```

While the function is running, I want to show an animation. The animation should end when the function process is finished.

```
myfunction # Start myFunction
myAnimation # Start myAnimation
# finish myFunction     
# finish myAnimation
```

I'm trying to use this nyancat animation https://github.com/klange/nyancat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have built *nyancat*, as described in the instructions on github, and placed it somewhere on the `PATH`:

```
worker() {
# some commands
# npm install
# kill some
#...
}

pidWorker=-1

myFunction() {
  worker > /dev/null 2>&1 &
  pidWorker=$!
}

observeMyFunction() {
  while kill -0 $pidWorker 2>/dev/null
  do
    sleep 1
  done
  pkill nyancat
  # clear the screen if you want, e.g. by using: printf "\033c"
}

myAnimation() {
  observeMyFunction &
  nyancat # maybe adapt the path
}

myFunction
myAnimation
```

The basic idea comes from [this blog](http://codingdiscovery.blogspot.com/2014/03/show-loading-dots-in-bash-script.html). *This answer has been edited according to the changed requirements*

Comment: I'm trying to use a nyancat animation (https://github.com/klange/nyancat) maybe could change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could imagine using `wait` which is waiting for the end of background process execution.
Then `kill` could be used to terminate the `myAnimation` function.

Give a try to this:

```
myfunction & 
myfunction_pid=$!
myAnimation &

wait "${myfunction_pid}" # wait the end of the myfunction running in background

printf "myfunction is done\n"

kill %% # send a signal to terminate all remaining background jobs
        # started by the current bash process: i.e. myAnimation
```